# How to compile indicator terminal? Fails with "A required package was not found" message

Tags: compiling, cmake, vala

I'm trying to compile this package from launchpad: https://code.launchpad.net/~tombeckmann/+junk/indicator-terminal

I installed valac, as the package has some vala code. And CMake, as there's a CMakeList.txt
I downloaded the code the code with bzr, and tried to compile with cmake:

```
biel@C3PO:~$ bzr branch lp:~tombeckmann/+junk/indicator-terminal
You have not informed bzr of your Launchpad ID, and you must do this to
write to Launchpad or access private data.  See "bzr help launchpad-login".
Branched 1 revision.                                                          
biel@C3PO:~$ cd indicator-terminal
biel@C3PO:~/indicator-terminal$ cmake CMakeLists.txt
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- checking for modules 'granite;indicator3-0.4;keybinder-3.0;vte-2.90'
--   package 'granite' not found
--   package 'indicator3-0.4' not found
--   package 'keybinder-3.0' not found
--   package 'vte-2.90' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:266 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:320 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:39 (pkg_check_modules)



-- Found Vala: /usr/bin/valac 
-- checking for a minimum Vala version of 0.16.1
--   found Vala, version 0.20.1
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:76 (install):
  install TARGETS given no LIBRARY DESTINATION for shared library target
  "indicator-terminal".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Try install all packages that are marked "not found" with apt-get

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Most questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives are classified as *off-topic*. This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ok Seth, sorry for the problem,and thanks by the help!

Comment: So, did you just install Ubuntu 12.04 and you are getting the same error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must install this packages:

```
sudo apt-get install pkg-config libgranite-dev libindicator3-dev libkeybinder-3.0-dev libvte-2.90-dev
```

Those are the exact package name from the [buildlog](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/148302681/buildlog.txt.gz).

Comment: Tks Braiam! I can't believe that was the problem...